# How can I change a games background when controlled object runs into the border of canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm somewhat new to coding. I currently have a code that creates a canvas for a controlled character to move around. So far I have it where if the character runs into the right border of the canvas, it will move the character to the left of the canvas. However I want to have the background change as well, showing the character has entered a new area. How would I go about doing this? The background is currently made with the use of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get your canvas into a variable. If it has an ID, you can use that:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("YOUR_CANVAS_ID_HERE");
```

Then use this code to set the canvas' background color:

```
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

That should be all you need!

Comment: So instead of using CSS to change the background, I should do it directly from JS?
Will I be able to then manipulate and replace that background color with trigger events such as the character hitting the right border of the canvas?

Comment: Yes. You only need to create the `canvas` variable once, and then you can set style.backgroundColor as often as you want. The part of that line in quotes can be any color that is accepted in CSS (so "red" would be fine, and so would "#f00", as well as "rgb(255, 0, 0)", among other things).